# What does Jesse Stuart mean by "weaker devour the stronger"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs

When I was reading the short story *Love* by Jesse Stuart, I came across this sentence,

> the **weaker devour stronger** even among human beings.

Can the *weak* really *devour* the *strong*? I think it would make more sense if "devour" was used in "*stronger* devour the *weaker*". So what does the author mean when she says that "weaker devour the stronger"?

Comment: Even after consulting dictionaries I find no relevant new meaning or use of *devour*, so I do not understand this usage. Perhaps a wider context might help.

Comment: [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/devour): devour somebody/something (formal) to destroy somebody/something The 'survival of the fittest' (/most powerful) in human society.

Comment: I don't know because I have always thought that the stronger devour the weaker.

Comment: As an aside, I've seen the reversed  'the weaker devour the stronger' (applied to human beings); it means that a lot of resources have to be poured into caring for the sick, the aged, orphans ... in a typical humanitarian society.

Comment: There seem a number of issues that might be raised here: the use of comparative adjectives as nouns; the metaphorical use of devour; the use of weaker with a plural verb; the article before weaker but not before stronger (which seems to be an error). The OP should explain what the problem is in more detail.

Answer (score 5):

This question is based on a misquotation. The sentence in question is [variously published](https://www.google.com/search?q=weaker+devour+stronger+even+among+human+beings+jesse+stuart) as

> - Weaker devour the stronger even among human beings.
> - Stronger devour the weaker even among human beings.

Given that the whole context is

> It is life. [...] devour the [...] even among human beings. Dog kills snake. Snake kills birds. Birds kill the butterflies. Man conquers all. Man, too, kills for sport.

... it seems highly likely that the **stronger devour the weaker.**

Of course, this doesn't actually mean *devour* as in *eat voraciously:* it's metaphorical, and [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/devour) has "to destroy somebody/something".

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a reference to a in Genesis.  Pharaoh describes his dream in which 7 thin and weak cows devour 7 fat cows, which Joseph interprets as the coming of 7 years of famine which will obliterate the 7 years of plenty that precede them.